# Pairwise priority queue

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, theorem-proving

I have a set of `A`'s and a set of `B`'s, each with an associated numerical priority, where each `A` may match some or all `B`'s and vice versa, and my main loop basically consists of:

Take the best `A` and `B` in priority order, and do stuff with `A` and `B`.

The most obvious way to do this is with a single priority queue of `(A,B)` pairs, but if there are 100,000 `A`'s and 100,000 `B`'s then the set of `O(N^2)` pairs won't fit in memory (and disk is too slow).

Another possibility is for each `A`, loop through every `B`. However this means that global priority ordering is by `A` only, and I really need to take priority of both components into account.

(The application is theorem proving, where the above options are called the pair algorithm and the given clause algorithm respectively; the shortcomings of each are known, but I haven't found any reference to a good solution.)

Some kind of two layer priority queue would seem indicated, but it's not clear how to do this without using either `O(N^2)` memory or `O(N^2)` time in the worst case.

Is there a known method of doing this?

Clarification: each `A` must be processed with all corresponding `B`'s, not just one.

Comment: What happens if there's an A with no corresponding B?

Comment: @Jason Punyon Then there is nothing to do.

Comment: "Each A may match some or all B's".  Ok, but how do we know WHICH B's a particular A matches?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's something I'm not understanding but,

Why not keep the A's and B's in separate heaps, get_Max on each of the heaps, do your work, remove each max from its associated heap and continue?

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the best pairs first, and if nothing good comes up mop up the rest with the given clause algorithm for completeness' sake. This may lead to some double work, but I'd bet that this is insignificant.

Have you considered ordered paramodulation or superposition?

Comment: Those are both on the to-do list, but I think I need to nail the basics down first. Right now I'm thinking in terms of using a series of pair queues, one per bucket.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the items in A have an individual priority, the items in B have an individual priority, and the (A,B) pairs have a combined priority.  Only the combined priority matters, but hopefully we can use the individual properties along the way.  However, there is also a matching relation between items in A and items in B that is independent priority.

I assume that, for all a in A, b1 and b2 in B, such that Match(a,b1) and Match(a,b2), then Priority(b1) >= Priority(b2) implies CombinedPriority(a,b1) >= CombinedPriority(a,b2).

Now, begin by sorting B in decreasing order priority.  Let B(j) indicate the jth element in this sorted order.  Also, let A(i) indicate the ith element of A (which may or may not be in sorted order).

Let nextb(i,j) be a function that finds the smallest j' >= j such that Match(A(i),B(j')).  If no such j' exists, the function returns null (or some other suitable error value).  Searching for j' may just involve looping upward from j, or we may be able to do something faster if we know more about the structure of the Match relation.

Create a priority queue Q containing (i,nextb(i,0)) for all indices i in A such that nextb(i,0) != null.  The pairs (i,j) in Q are ordered by CombinedPriority(A(i),B(j)).

Now just loop until Q is empty.  Pull out the highest-priority pair (i,j) and process (A(i),B(j)) appropriately.  Then re-insert (i,nextb(i,j+1)) into Q (unless nextb(i,j+1) is null).

Altogether, this takes O(N^2 log N) time in the worst case that all pairs match.  In general, it takes O(N^2 + M log N) where M are the number of matches.  The N^2 component can be reduced if there is a faster way of calculating nextb(i,j) that just looping upward, but that depends on knowledge of the Match relation.

(In the above analysis, I assumed both A and B were of size N.  The formulas could easily be modified if they are different sizes.)

You seemed to want something better than O(N^2) time in the worst case, but if you need to process every match, then you have a lower bound of M, which can be N^2 itself.  I don't think you're going to be able to do better than O(N^2 log N) time unless there is some special structure to the combined priority that lets you use a better-than-log-N priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a Set of A's, and a set of B's, and you need to pick a (A, B) pair from this set such that some f(a, b) is the highest of any other (A, B) pair.

This means you can either store all possible (A, B) pairs and order them, and just pick the highest each time through the loop (O(1) per iteration but O(N*M) memory).

Or you could loop through all possible pairs and keep track of the current maximum and use that (O(N*M) per iteration, but only O(N+M) memory).

If I am understanding you correctly this is what you are asking.

*I think it very much depends on f() to determine if there is a better way to do it.*

If f(a, b) = a + b, then it is obviously very simple, the highest A, and the highest B are what you want.

Comment: f(a,b) is simple, max(a,b) is a tolerable first approximation.

But how to perform many iterations without using O(N*M) time or memory?

Answer (score 0):

I think your original idea will work, you just need to keep your As and Bs in separate collections and just stick references to them in your priority queue.  If each reference takes 16 bytes (just to pick a number), then 10,000,000 A/B references will only take ~300M.  Assuming your As and Bs themselves aren't too big, it should be workable.